# Responsive Gmail signature

Tags: html, gmail

I need your help to make a Gmail signature responsive.

I tried many things (different ... in the head for each media queries, etc.), went to different Q&A on Stackoverflow but nothing resolved my problem.

I also followed the developer guidelines from [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css).

What I need is a responsive signature when I go to the mobile version of Gmail. (cf the class="mobile-view").

If you have different approaches than this one, I'll be happy to try them out !

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
            .mobile-view {display: none !important;}
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
            .desktop-view {display: none !important;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="desktop-view" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <a href="http://www.optimize-matter.com/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Internal&utm_campaign=lien_signature">
                                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="150">
                                    </a>
                                </td>


                                <td width="20">
                                    <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td color="#95c8c1" direction="vertical" width="1" class="sc-jhAzac hmXDXQ" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(149, 200, 193);"></td>
                                <td width="20">
                                    <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                                </td>


                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <h3 color="#000000" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                        <span style="font-size: 13px;">Name ●</span> 
                                                        <span style="font-size: 11px;">Job</span>
                                                    </h3>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                    <span color="#95c8c1" width="11" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#95c8c1" width="13" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                    <a href="00 00 00 00 00" color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>00 00 00 00 00</span>
                                                    </a> | 
                                                    <a href="00 00 00 00 00 " color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>00 00 00 00 00</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                    <span color="#95c8c1" width="11" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#95c8c1" width="13" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                    <a href="mailto:name@job.com" color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>name@job.com</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                    <span color="#95c8c1" width="11" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/address-icon-2x.png" color="#95c8c1" width="13" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                    <span color="#000000" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                        <span>Adress</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10">
                                                    <div></div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="display: flex; margin-top: 10px;">
                                                    <a href="#" color="#6A78D1" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/twitter-icon-2x.png" alt="twitter" color="#6A78D1" height="24" style="background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193); max-width: 135px; display: block;">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div width="10"></div>
                                                    <a href="#" color="#6A78D1" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(106, 120, 209);">
                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/linkedin-icon-2x.png" alt="linkedin" color="#6A78D1" height="24" style="background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193); max-width: 135px; display: block;">
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 40px;"></div>
                                </td>

                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/75" width="75">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="15"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td color="#95c8c1" direction="vertical" style="border-bottom: none; border-top: 1px solid rgb(149, 200, 193); margin-bottom: 10px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 11px; font-style: italic">Lorem ipsum  <a href="mailto:support@job.com"><span>support@job.com</span></a></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<table class="mobile-view" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" width="150">
                                    </a>
                                </td>


                                <td width="20">
                                    <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td color="#95c8c1" direction="vertical" width="1" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(149, 200, 193);"></td>
                                <td width="20">
                                    <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                                </td>


                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Tahoma;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td>
                                                    <h3 color="#000000" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                        <span style="font-size: 11px;">Name Lastname</span>
                                                    </h3>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <h3 color="#000000" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                        <span style="font-size: 9px;">Job name</span>
                                                    </h3>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                    <a href="tel:00 00 00 00 00" color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>00 00 00 00 00</span>
                                                    </a> | 
                                                    <a href="tel:00 00 00 00 00" color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>00 00 00 00 00 </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                    <a href="mailto:name@job.com" color="#000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;">
                                                        <span>name@job.com</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                    <span color="#000000" style="font-size: 10px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                                        <span>13 Adress of Company</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="display: flex; margin-top: 10px;">
                                                    <a href="#" color="#6A78D1" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193);">
                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/twitter-icon-2x.png" alt="twitter" color="#6A78D1" height="24" style="background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193); max-width: 135px; display: block;">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div width="10"></div>
                                                    <a href="#" color="#6A78D1" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(106, 120, 209);">
                                                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/linkedin-icon-2x.png" alt="linkedin" color="#6A78D1" height="24" style="background-color: rgb(149, 200, 193); max-width: 135px; display: block;">
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="15"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td color="#95c8c1" direction="vertical" style="border-bottom: none; border-top: 1px solid rgb(149, 200, 193); margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span style="font-size: 9px; font-style: italic">Lorem ipsum <a href="mailto:support@job.com"><span>support@job.com</span></a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `@@media only screen and`

```
<style type="text/css">
        @@media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
            .mobile-view {display: none !important;}
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        @@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
            .desktop-view {display: none !important;}
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Have you seen my code ? Your response is not changing a lot of things.